# using powershell pipes to output property of matchitem object

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a powershell pipe to do the following which doesn't work. Has anyone got a suggestion on how I can do this in one step

```
$a = bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" | $-.line
```

at the moment I'm needing to do the following

```
$aobj = bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current"  
$a = $aobj.line
```

Is there a way I can combine this into one line?

Comment: Couldn't you also do `bcdedit /enum "{current}"` in PowerShell to get the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work provided you are pulling a single line from the BCDEDIT output:

```
$a = (bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current").line
```

If you might get multiple lines, the following will return an array of lines:

```
$a = bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" | foreach-object { $_.Line }
```

Take you pick :)

Comment: The first of these will also work just fine for multiple lines provided you are using at least Powershell 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a property of an object by itself, the usual way to do it is with  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`.

```
bcdedit /enum | select-string "identifier.*current" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```

Comment: Yes - that's certainly more elegant than using foreach-object.